# Get first N elements of parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I have to following problem:

```
template< size_t... N_i >
class A
{
  // ...
};

template< size_t N, size_t... N_i >
A</* first N elements of N_i...*/> foo()
{
  A</* first N elements of N_i...*/> a;

  // ...

  return a;
}

int main()
{
  A<1,2> res = foo<2, 1,2,3,4>();

  return 0;
}
```

Here, I want `foo` to have the return type `A</* first N size_t of N_i...*/>`, i.e., the `class A` which has as template arguments the first N elements of the parameter pack `N_i`.

Does anyone know how this can be implemented?

Comment: Lots of minging recursion

Comment: Thank you. Is there no "elegant" solution?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert: You're doing C++ template metaprogramming, and you want an "elegant" solution? 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sometimes it's not impossible ;)

Comment: @krzaq Probably also _this_ time it's not impossible. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a slight variation on [@skypjack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113640/4987285) that avoids using tuples:

```
template <size_t... N_i,size_t... M_i>
auto foo2(std::index_sequence<M_i...>)
{
    constexpr size_t values[] = {N_i...};
    return A<values[M_i]...>();
}

template <size_t N,size_t... N_i>
auto foo()
{
    return foo2<N_i...>(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Comment: You missed something in your _slight variation_. As it is it cannot be used anymore in a constant expression. You should add a `constexpr` in front of the functions. If you decide to copy an answer, do it to the end. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Here is the shortest solution that came to my mind (with two lines spent for an alias).
It follows a minimal, working example based on the code posted by the OP:

```
#include<functional>
#include<cstddef>
#include<utility>
#include<tuple>

template<std::size_t... V>
class A {};

template<std::size_t... V, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto func(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return A<std::get<I>(std::make_tuple(V...))...>{};
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... V>
constexpr auto func() {
    return func<V...>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... V>
using my_a = decltype(func<N, V...>());

int main() {
    A<1,2> res1 = func<2, 1, 2, 3, 4>();
    // Or even better...
    decltype(func<2, 1, 2, 3, 4>()) res2{};
    // Or even better...
    my_a<2, 1, 2, 3, 4> res3{};
}
```

Comment: That's a great use of `constexpr`ness of `make_tuple` and `get`.

Comment: @krzaq Thank you. Hope this helps the OP.

Answer (score 9):

The most direct subproblem is in the land of typelists:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct typelist {
    using type = typelist;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template <std::size_t N, class TL>
struct head_n {
    using type = ???;
};
```

Now, `head_n` is just a matter of simple recursion - move an element from one list to another list `N` times starting from an empty list.

```
template <std::size_t N, class R, class TL>
struct head_n_impl;

// have at least one to pop from and need at least one more, so just 
// move it over
template <std::size_t N, class... Ts, class U, class... Us>
struct head_n_impl<N, typelist<Ts...>, typelist<U, Us...>>
: head_n_impl<N-1, typelist<Ts..., U>, typelist<Us...>>
{ };

// we have two base cases for 0 because we need to be more specialized
// than the previous case regardless of if we have any elements in the list
// left or not
template <class... Ts, class... Us>
struct head_n_impl<0, typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>>
: tag<typelist<Ts...>>
{ };

template <class... Ts, class U, class... Us>
struct head_n_impl<0, typelist<Ts...>, typelist<U, Us...>>
: tag<typelist<Ts...>>
{ };

template <std::size_t N, class TL>
using head_n = typename head_n_impl<N, typelist<>, TL>::type;
```

Going from this to your specific problem I leave as an exercise to the reader.

---

An alternate approach is via concatenation. Convert every element of a `typelist<Ts...>` into either a `typelist<T>` or a `typelist<>`, and then concat them all together. `concat` is straightforward:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct concat { };

template <class TL>
struct concat<TL>
: tag<TL>
{ };

template <class... As, class... Bs, class... Rest>
struct concat<typelist<As...>, typelist<Bs...>, Rest...>
: concat<typelist<As..., Bs...>, Rest...>
{ };
```

And then we can do:

```
template <std::size_t N, class TL, class = std::make_index_sequence<TL::size>>
struct head_n;

template <std::size_t N, class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct head_n<N, typelist<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
: concat<
        std::conditional_t<(Is < N), typelist<Ts>, typelist<>>...
        >
{ };

template <std::size_t N, class TL>
using head_n_t = typename head_n<N, TL>::type;
```

The advantage of this latter approach is that `concat` can be replaced in C++17 by a fold-expression given an appropriate `operator+`:

```
template <class... As, class... Bs>
constexpr typelist<As..., Bs...> operator+(typelist<As...>, typelist<Bs...> ) {
    return {};
}
```

which allows:

```
template <std::size_t N, class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct head_n<N, typelist<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = decltype(
        (std::conditional_t<(Is < N), typelist<Ts>, typelist<>>{} + ... + typelist<>{})
        );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple with [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html):

```
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<size_t... vals>
auto make_a(hana::tuple<hana::integral_constant<size_t, vals>...>)
{
    return A<vals...>{};
}

template<size_t N, size_t... vals>
auto foo(){
    constexpr auto front = hana::take_front(
        hana::tuple_c<size_t, vals...>,
        hana::integral_c<size_t,N>
    );
    return detail::make_a(front);
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jgSnSdtvQ7gnPEca)

Answer (score 3):

You could also make use of variadic generic lambda expression and reusable helper structure to perform compile-time iteration:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct iterate;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct iterate<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
   template <class Lambda>
   auto operator()(Lambda lambda) {
      return lambda(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}...);
   }
};

template <size_t... Is>
struct A { };

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
auto foo() {
   return iterate<N>{}([](auto... ps){
      using type = std::tuple<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>;
      return A<std::tuple_element_t<ps, type>{}...>{};
   });
}

int main() {
   decltype(foo<3, 1, 2, 3, 4>()) a; // == A<1, 2, 3> a;
}
```

Comment: @skypjack by the way I actually think this solution isn't tricky at all and may be quite extensible :)

Comment: Do not misunderstand, I like the way you combined defaulted parameter, partial specialization and lambda function. I only guess it's too tricky for the specific case. I'm of the party for which if you can do it in a line, you should not waste the one below. That's all. Nice solution anyway. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack Well I guess its a good party ;) Yet I might also be misunderstood... Once struct `iterate` is created you could use it whenever compile-time iteration over `N` elements is needed. This would make other places where you previously needed to create two functions -- the one with `std::make_index_sequence<N>` and its `impl` version with `std::index_sequence<Is...>` unnecessary. Do you get my point now? :)

Comment: I got it two or three comments ago. :-D ... I see what you mean, but still I guess you can write it in a more compact form. Anyway, I like this for it's a brain-gym one. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack hah brain-gym I gotta remember that :) Well you confused me with the `I'm of the party for which if you can do it in a line, you should not waste the one below` comment :) To be honest I also think your solution could actually be the best for OP, but maybe someone else in the future might find the code better in his or hers particular problem :)

Comment: You can reduce `decltype(ps)::value` to just `ps`. And the whole `tuple_element` stuff to `A<std::tuple_element_t<ps, type>{}...>{}`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, such method requires to define additional Helper types

```
template< size_t... N_i >
class A
{
};

template <size_t... N_i>
struct Helper;

template <size_t... N_i>
struct Helper<0, N_i...>
{
    typedef A<> type;
};

template <size_t N0, size_t... N_i>
struct Helper<1, N0, N_i...>
{
    typedef A<N0> type;
};

template <size_t N0, size_t N1, size_t... N_i>
struct Helper<2, N0, N1, N_i...>
{
    typedef A<N0, N1> type;
};

template< size_t N, size_t... N_i >
typename Helper<N, N_i...>::type foo()
{
  typename Helper<N, N_i...>::type a;
  return a;
}
```